ISM project file name in InstallScript project
I have two installers, a "Full" installer that contains all of the prerequisites and an "Incremental" installer that does not. The incremental installer is used by those who've already installed a previous version of our product and don't want to wait for the larger full installer to d/l.
There are functions in the full installer that are not called in the incremental, and these generate warnings. I'd like to eliminate these warnings.
If I could determine the ISM file name at compile time I could use a #ifdef or similar construct to avoid those warnings. Other options?
Thanks!
